# How to adjust images width in IE8 and Below

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I am trying the following approach which does show the image and scales the image accordingly. However, I would like to have the width to be not at 100% but at 80%. Is there a way I can achieve this and use the following approach below?

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='ColoradoConnectBanner.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
```

Comment: I think you need to use another element inside this one, that has a width of 80% of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You could not set the width by modifying the filter you've used.

[AlphaImageLoader Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms532969(v=vs.85)) has limited objects which do not include setting the width.

If you want to set the width of your picture, you could put the picture in a container like div and set the "width" attribute to achieve your requirement.

For more about the related problem, you could click the following thread links. Maybe you could get some ideas from them.

1.[How do I make background-size work in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/how-do-i-make-background-size-work-in-ie)

2.[progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader causing links to be unclickable in ie8, ie7, and ie6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102594/progiddximagetransform-microsoft-alphaimageloader-causing-links-to-be-unclickab)

I've made a sample and you could refer to.
CSS.

```
.imageWrapper {
        display: block;
        width: 80%;
        height: 500px;
        background-image: url(Images/test2.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='Images/test2.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='Images/test2.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
    }

    .ie6 .imageWrapper,
    .ie7 .imageWrapper,
    .ie8 .imageWrapper {
        background-image: none;
    }
```

HTML.

```
<div class="imageWrapper">
    testtesttesttest
    testtesttesttest
</div>
```

EDIT: Here is my wroking result:[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IhEH.jpg)

Comment: @ Jenifer Jiang: The issue I have is I am not able to find the particular file/access to the file where the image is being used. The only file i have access to is the css file which I am trying to adjust the size by using css only

Comment: Why you could not find the file? Your image path is the relative path of the current project. src="the relative path". If there is no related file, there will not show the image.

Comment: @ Jenifer Jiang: I am talking about regarding the index file where the image is being used. However, I was able to figure it out using first-child and using a hack that I found for IE8 and below